# How to create 'Global' popup modal in react native?

Tags: react-native

Let's say i have a "Food Ordering App" and it 3 screens(home, order, setting).  I wanna make a global popup modal that can be show up anywhere(from the whole screen) and anytime when the app get the food order from the service. I have a few questions regarding to this:

> 1. where should i put my popup modal component ?
> 2. how to triggered this popup modal ?

Comment: you'll have to use events for this

Comment: @JuniusL.what event did you mean?

Comment: I've created  a simple example see https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/8eff36

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
<Modal animationType = "fade" transparent = {false} visible = {true//or some logic} style = {{padding:0}} presentationStyle = "overFullScreen">
 // some content ...
</Modal>
```

Don't forget to import Modal from 'react-native'